# RTL8814 Firmware needed

Tags: drivers, realtek-wireless

Unable to find firmware for ALFA AWUS1900 card.

Driver works ok, but I see following messages at dmesg

```
[129914.853240] Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8814aufw.bin
[129914.853255] usb 2-2.3: firmware: failed to load rtlwifi/rtl8814aufw.bin (-2)
[129914.853257] usb 2-2.3: Direct firmware load for rtlwifi/rtl8814aufw.bin failed with error -2
[129914.853259] RTL871X: rtl8814au_hal_init: Download Firmware failed!!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to download firmware from [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/ulli-kroll/rtl8814au) and place it in corresponding folder:

```
sudo wget https://github.com/ulli-kroll/rtl8814au/blob/master/firmware/rtl8814aufw.bin?raw=true \
-O /lib/firmware/rtlwifi/rtl8814aufw.bin
```

And reconnect your Alfa.

Comment: thx works perfect